# CodeIgniter will not load a specific controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I am having a weird issue in which CodeIgniter (3.1) will not load a specific controller. I can load other controllers, but when I create a controller with the name sppb, using any case combination, and save the file as sppb.php it does not load.

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

   class Sppb extends CI_Controller {
      public function __construct()
      {
        parent::__construct();
      }

      public function index()
      {
      }
}
```

Above is the entire controller and it is saved to the server with the corresponding name of sppb.php.

I have also taken a different controller that I can load, copied it into a new file, changed the name to sppb, saved it to the server and it still will not load.

This is on a Linux server and I have checked the case in the naming of the file and the Controller.

Comment: class Sppb extends CI_Controller

Comment: Partly right, but my main issue was the Filename also needed to be uppercase. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Just like [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming) say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Class file name needs to be 1st letter upper case... like

```
Sppb.php
```

The same applies to your class names

```
class Sppb extends CI_Controller {
```

Comment: I had previously commented that I had tried this, then I reread your response. You are right. I had not for some reason tested with both File and Class uppercased. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I was kind of betting on that... Glad it was worth the gamble.